# FileNotFoundError: scipy.libs

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, exe, cx-freeze

I'm trying to build an exe file using cx_Freeze.

But when I run the resulting file I get an error:

> FileNotFoundError: ..\build\exe.win-amd64-3.8\lib\scipy.libs

Please tell me how to fix this problem?

I run the following code:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

build_exe_options = {"packages": ["torch", 'tensorflow']}

target = Executable(
    script='sub.py'
)
setup(
    name='my',
    options={'build_exe': build_exe_options},
    executables=[target]
)
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this exact problem, this is only a short term fix but if you search for 'scipy.libs' in your python install location 'site-packages' folder (or virtual environment if you're using one) and copy/paste it into the libs folder in your build it should solve the issue.

I'll edit my answer if I come across the root cause and a more permanent fix...

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `include_files` option of the `build_exe` command. According to the [cx_Freeze documentation](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup_script.html#cmdoption-arg-include_files), you can use a tuple `(source, destination)` in the `include_files` list to let cx_Freeze copy a file to a specific destination into the build directory:

> this list will contain strings or 2-tuples for the source and destination; the source can be a file or a directory (in which case the tree is copied except for .svn and CVS directories); the target must not be an absolute path

Accordingly, try to add the following lines to your `setup.py` file:

```py
import os
import scipy
scipy_libs_source = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(scipy.__file__)), 'scipy.libs')
scipy_libs_destination = os.path.join('lib', 'scipy.libs')
include_files = [(scipy_libs_source, scipy_libs_destination)]
build_exe_options = {'include_files': include_files,
                     'packages': ['torch', 'tensorflow']}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not find the scipy.libs, but even just making an empty file with that name helped