# Freezing code and including .libs folders

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I have a successful build of a python 3.9 program I'm working on. However, the following folders need to be manually copied into the lib folder;

- pyproj.libs
- scipy.libs
- Shapely.libs

I have the setup.py, how do I set it up so that these folders are copied to the correct location?

Here's my `options` definition:

```
options = {
    'build_exe': {
        'includes': [
                    ],
        'packages': [
                     'PyQt5',
                     'scipy',
                     'os',
                     'sys',
                     'datetime',
                     'pandas',
                     'scipy.spatial.distance',
                     'open3d',
                     'geopandas',
                     'laspy',
                     'numpy',
                     'alphashape',
                     'shapely.speedups'

                    ],
        'excludes': [
            'tkinter', 'matplotlib', 'sqlite3'
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, so the `"include_files":[...]` does the trick, although it copies `pyproj.libs` to the `build` directory rather than the `build/lib`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FileNotFoundError: scipy.libs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74454338/filenotfounderror-scipy-libs)